# C# HttpWebRequest website sign in

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest

I am trying to switch from a web browser control to http requests for automating tasks for speed.
With this function I can post data and receive a logged in page, but no cookies are returned and added to the cookies list so the logged in session isnt passed on to the next request.

```
    //an example call        
    test("http://websitename.com/loginpage.php", "username=foo&password=123456");

    private string test(string url, string data)
    {
        string responseFromServer;

        byte[] byteArray;

        Stream dataStream;

        HttpWebRequest request;

        HttpWebResponse response;

        StreamReader reader;


        responseFromServer = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            foreach(Cookie a in cookies)
                request.CookieContainer.Add(a);

            dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            foreach(Cookie a in response.Cookies)
                cookies.Add(a);

            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            x.ToString();
        }

        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

How can I keep it logged in?

Comment: Can you include the entire HTTP response (including headers)?  (For example, by using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/).)

Answer (score 8):

This is final answer:

```
string url = "http://www.ABC/MemberShip/Login.aspx";// HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Replace("AutoLogin", "Login");

CookieContainer myCookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;
request.Method = "GET";
request.KeepAlive = false;

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
string srcString = reader.ReadToEnd();

// get the page ViewState                
string viewStateFlag = "id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"";
int i = srcString.IndexOf(viewStateFlag) + viewStateFlag.Length;
int j = srcString.IndexOf("\"", i);
string viewState = srcString.Substring(i, j - i);

// get page EventValidation                
string eventValidationFlag = "id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"";
i = srcString.IndexOf(eventValidationFlag) + eventValidationFlag.Length;
j = srcString.IndexOf("\"", i);
string eventValidation = srcString.Substring(i, j - i);

string submitButton = "LoginButton";

// UserName and Password
string userName = "userid";
string password = "password";
// Convert the text into the url encoding string
viewState = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(viewState);
eventValidation = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(eventValidation);
submitButton = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(submitButton);

// Concat the string data which will be submit
string formatString =
         "txtUserName={0}&txtPassword={1}&btnSignIn={2}&__VIEWSTATE={3}&__EVENTVALIDATION={4}";
string postString =
         string.Format(formatString, userName, password, submitButton, viewState, eventValidation);

// Convert the submit string data into the byte array
byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postString);

// Set the request parameters
request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.Referer = url;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; CIBA)";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;
System.Net.Cookie ck = new System.Net.Cookie("TestCookie1", "Value of test cookie");
ck.Domain = request.RequestUri.Host;
request.CookieContainer.Add(ck);
request.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);

request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

// Submit the request data
System.IO.Stream outputStream = request.GetRequestStream();
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
outputStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
outputStream.Close();


// Get the return data
response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
srcString = reader.ReadToEnd();
Response.Write(srcString);
Response.End();
```

Comment: To qualify as an answer this piece of code requires explanation (I believe here at stackoverflow no answer can be defined final by just saying so, thus the remark is improper)

Comment: The code should also dispose of things that implement IDisposable

Answer (score 1):

This post seems to have an answer with positive vote count: [C# keep session id over httpwebrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453560/c-keep-session-id-over-httpwebrequest)

Create a CookieContainer instance in your first request to the server, and instead of creating a new one for your next request, re-use that instance.